# OutOfMemory Error while trying to extract a large jar using ZipFileSet

Tags: java, out-of-memory, zip

With jdk1.5, i get an OutofMemoryError while trying to extract a reasonably large jar.
However, this does not happen on jdk6. Is it because of different default heap-size/permgen settings on jdk1.5 and jdk6 or is this a bug in jdk1.5 that was fixed in jdk6?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.*;

public class UnZip {
   final int BUFFER = 2048;
   public static void main (String argv[]) {
      try {
         BufferedOutputStream dest = null;
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(argv[0]);
         ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis));
         ZipEntry entry;
         while((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Extracting: " +entry);
            int count;
            byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
            // write the files to the disk
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(entry.getName());
            dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, BUFFER);
            while ((count = zis.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
               dest.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            dest.flush();
            dest.close();
         }
         zis.close();
      } catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using jdk1.5 with increased heap size?

Comment: Yeah, i have tried that and it works. But it works on jdk6 without increasing any heap-size settings.

Comment: Could you provide some lines of code that show how you extracted the jar?

Comment: On a different note, move the close() calls into finally block. If some exception has occurred earlier on it would prevent the connection from being released. finally {...} ensures that the close() is executed always.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting the [Total Heap Size](http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc5.0/gc_tuning_5.html#0.0.0.%20Total%20Heap|outline) section of [Tuning Garbage Collection with the 5.0 Java[tm] Virtual Machine](http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc5.0/gc_tuning_5.html):

> #### Total Heap
>
> (...)
>
> By default, the virtual machine grows
>   or shrinks the heap at each collection
>   to try to keep the proportion of free
>   space to live objects at each
>   collection within a specific range.
>   This target range is set as a
>   percentage by the parameters
>   `-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=<minimum>` and `-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=<maximum>`, and the total size is bounded below by
>   `-Xms` and above by `-Xmx` . The default parameters for the 32-bit Solaris
>   Operating System (SPARC Platform
>   Edition) are shown in this table:
>
> ```
> -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio= 40
> -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio= 70
> -Xms          3670k
> -Xmx          64m
> ```
>
> Default values of heap size parameters
>   on 64-bit systems have been scaled up
>   by approximately 30%. This increase is
>   meant to compensate for the larger
>   size of objects on a 64-bit system.

And in [Default Heap Size](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/gc/gc_tuning_6.html#par_gc.ergonomics.default_size) of [Java SE 6 HotSpot Virtual Machine Garbage Collection Tuning](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/gc/gc_tuning_6.html), they write:

> #### Default Heap Size
>
> If not otherwise set on the command line, the initial and maximum heap sizes are calculated based on the amount of memory on the machine. The proportion of memory to use for the heap is controlled by the command line options `DefaultInitialRAMFraction` and `DefaultMaxRAMFraction`, as shown in the table below. (In the table, memory represents the amount of memory on the machine.)
>
> ```
>                                              Formula  Default
> initial heap size     memory / DefaultInitialRAMFraction          memory / 64
> maximum heap size     MIN(memory / DefaultMaxRAMFraction, 1GB)    MIN(memory / 4, 1GB)
> ```
>
> Note that the default maximum heap size will not exceed 1GB, regardless of how much memory is installed on the machine.

So, yes, Java 6 has very different heap settings and the heap can grow to 1/4 of your RAM (or 1GB if you have more than 4GB) i.e. very likely much more than 64m nowadays.